# Could someone check my work for this problem for vectors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Find the angle  between the two planes. (Round your answer to two decimal places. If the planes do not intersect, enter DNE.)
I found this to be 65.28°

(b) Find parametric equations of their line of intersection. (Let $z = t$, then solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in terms of $t$. If the planes do not intersect, enter DNE.)

$x −  3y + z    =  −5$
$3x  +  2z +  5  =  0$

My try: $3x + 2z + 5 = 0  ⇒  x = \frac{1}{3}(-2z-5)$

Then $3y = x + z + 5$
$3y= \frac{1}{3}(2z-5)+z+5 =  \frac{z+10}{3} \implies y = \frac{z+10}{9}$

Let $z = t$. Parametric equations: $x=-\frac{2t}{3}-\frac{5}{3},\ y=\frac{t}{9}+\frac{10}{9},\ z=t$

Comment: If you write using mathjax, it will help.

Comment: Please use titles that are informative about the content; to ask people to check your work, use the [solution-verification] tag.

Comment: got it! It's edited already.

Comment: But most of your working is still not readable. To begin with, please use \$ sign around your math so we can follow.

Comment: I'm not sure where it isn't readable, could you help edit? I seems fine to me1

Comment: Angle is OK. Line method is fine, did not check the algebra though.

Comment: I already edited and that is why it seems fine. Checked part (b). It is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos^{-1} \left( \frac{3+2}{\sqrt{(1^2+3^2+1)(3^2+2^2)}}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left( \frac{5}{\sqrt{143}}\right)\approx 65.28^\circ$$

To verify your solution, we just have to substitute them in:

$$x-3y+z=-\frac{2t}{3}-\frac53-\frac{t}3-\frac{10}3+t=-5$$

$$3x+2z+5=-2t-5+2t+5=0$$

It is fine.

Comment: hmm, for some reason it's wrong!

Comment: why do you say so? can you give me more context?

Comment: I entered it into an online grading system for homework.

Comment: perhaps check your formatting, for example, some system requires multiplication to be typed out explicitly such as $-\frac13 \cdot t$.